# Safari -webkit-optimize-contrast not working for background images

Tags: html, css, image, safari, webkit

I want to disable blur of background image in html element (it should always be pixilated for scaling). I used the following code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<style>
#chart { 
  height: 300px; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-image: url('image.jpg');
  background-position: 0 0; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 300px;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* Legal fallback */
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox        */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera          */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Safari         */
  image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed  */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;               /* CSS4 Proposed  */
  image-rendering: pixelated;                 /* CSS4 Proposed  */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+           */
}
</style>
```

It seems to work in all browsers except Safari. Although, it works in Safari if I apply css directly to `img` element instead of `div` or if I remove `background-size` property.

I also found it was reported as a bug in 2012 https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97991, but it's status is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is fixed in Safari Technology Preview